# How to compare column values with first and last value of column python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe with column A.I want to compare all rows of column A with first row of column and then compare all rows  with last row of column if any value match with first or last row add flag column and give 0 if not match then give 1.

Note: when compare all rows with first row not include last row 
when compare all rows with last row not include first row

so i need to know any value in column is same as first value or last value and give flag

Comment: Refer [How to create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) for select first and last value by indexing, check membership by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and cast to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping, then set first and last value to `0` use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with position for `flag` column by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [2,3,4,2,6],
})

df['flag'] = df['A'].isin(df['A'].iloc[[0, -1]]).astype(int)
#alternative
#df['flag'] = np.where(df['A'].isin(df['A'].iloc[[0, -1]]), 1, 0)

df.iloc[[0, -1], df.columns.get_loc('flag')] = 0
print (df)
   A  flag
0  2     0
1  3     0
2  4     0
3  2     1
4  6     0
```

Comment: i just want to compare any value between first and last row is same with first row or last row , if yes then give flag 0, for example [2,3,4,2,6] in this column matched 4th value with first value ok my condition is stisfied just give flag 0

Comment: you are right , but i need answer  in yes or no , means if any value matched to start to or end value say yes (flag 1) if not matched say no (flag 0)  need answer only one row

Comment: @Edward - Not sure if understand, do you need `df['flag'] = np.where(df['A'].isin(df['A'].iloc[[0, -1]]), 'yes', 'no')

df.iloc[[0, -1], df.columns.get_loc('flag')] = 'no'` ?